# Error in creating query in openbravo through hql

Tags: hql, postgresql-8.4, openbravo

This question might have answer ... But not for openbravo with postgresql database.

I have openbravo 3.0 framework. In my window i have two date fields namely fromdate and todate. The requirement is i have to write a hql where clause to filter the records on the basis of current date.The date field is of timestamp without timezone.

Means **fromdate < currentdate**

and **todate > currentdate .**

I went through this  [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) and wrote the hql  where clause as

**e.id in(select s.id  from Tablename as s where s.fromdate <  current_Date and s.todate>current_date)**

when i open this window i get this error as

**Exception when creating query select e from Tablename as e 
where ( e.id in(select s.Tablename_ID from Tablename as s where s.fromdate < (current_date) and s.todate < (current_date)**

however if i remove the current date conditions as

e.id in(select s.id  from Tablename as s).. It is working fine.

Is it because of current_Date function ? .I tried even with now function .. but i get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**!!! Got The Error.**
There is a problem in the query i wrote , in the where clause i am selecting the id's which is not correct,hence  when i gave the below query it was running correctly.

**(Tablename.fromdate < currrent_date and TableName.todate>current_date)** There was no problem with the current_date function.

I thought may be it would help some one!!!

**Tip:** If you want to write hql query correctly in openbravo , pls install the **Hql query tool**  module that is available freely for community edition of openbravo.

Happy Coding